# Web API - Get RouteData, Action or Controller in DelegationHandler from HttpRequestMessage

Tags: asp.net-web-api, routes, asp.net-web-api2

I am having a difficulty to get route data, action or controller in DelegatingHandler.

```
public class LoggingHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {

        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var routeData = request.GetRouteData();
```

in this example routeData is always null. Is there any way how to get the context of the Web API controllers and thus actions so I could tell what action the URL is trying to invoke?

Comment: what kind of host are you using...IIS or Selfhost? this matters as route matching happens are different places depending on the host type...for example, in IIS's case earlier than when message handlers are executed, but in case of Selfhost its after the message handlers are executed..

Comment: Hello Kiran, it is self hosted.

Comment: if that is the case, then no, its not going to be available in the handler you are writing...but there are also `per-route` message handlers which run after route matching, so you could probably use it...an old stack diagram which can still apply: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kiranchalla/archive/2012/05/06/asp-net-mvc4-web-api-stack-diagram-currently-in-development.aspx

Comment: @KiranChalla if you post your comment as an answer i can accept it.